# Does "bada boom" actually refer to the crash of the Mondoshawan vessel?

Tags: languages, translation, the-fifth-element

I always took Leeloo's Divine Language monologue in Korben's cab to be a description of her escape from the regeneration chamber, and "bada boom" her term for the subsequent fall through the roof of the taxi.

However, the other day, I caught the mention of *Mondoshawans*. It is clearly heard here at 00:20 in this clip:

I also realized that some of her hand gestures and sound effects could be a description of the Mangalore attack and the crash of the Mondoshawan vessel.

Do we know for sure what she was actually saying here?

Comment: I think your problem was that the preview won't show in the question until the question is posted, but you just need to add the (YouTube) URL in the body.

Comment: @NKC...thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying and failing to find a copy of the script (hoping that either production notes would tell us, or that there'd be some clues in the lines themselves). There's a 1995 draft but that doesn't contain this exchange.

Comment: @LightnessRacesWithMonica - The novelisation, which appears to be based on a later version of the script (but not the final screenplay) has the exchange but no conclusive translation

Comment: According to a Yahoo movie biography of Milla Jovovich, "_The Fifth Element_ required her to co-create and master a 400-word alien language, while performing numerous action sequences." Evidently the words do mean something. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20110628202921/http://movies.yahoo.com/movie/contributor/1800022709/bio

Comment: If anyone wants to try their hand at transcribing, here is a purported vocabulary of Leeloo's "Divine Language". Good luck!
https://everything2.com/title/Leeloo%2527s+Language

Comment: I think it is entirely possible that it refers to the crash of the Mondoshawan vessel, because although only a hand remained, the character clearly has Dune style genetic memory.